# How to Print a Pointed to Array of Integers Inside a Struct Inside a Vector

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

```
struct x {
    unsigned int y;
    unsigned int *ptr;
};

std::vector<struct x> z;
```

I want to access the integer array pointed to by `ptr`. 
`z[0].y` will properly return the element `y` from the first struct in the vector.

How can I print the array pointed to by ptr inside of the first struct?

Comment: What's the problem with using `z[0].ptr[i]` where `i` is the index you want to access?

Comment: The ptr is storing the address of another allocated array. It doesn't point to a chunk of allocated memory.

Comment: It's pointing to an allocated array, but it doesn't point to allocated memory? That is contradicting itself ;). Do you mean nothing was ever assigned to `ptr`? Then you should do that first, before trying to read from it. What about using a `std::vector<unsigned int>` instead of the `unsigned int*`? As long as you don't want many of your structs to point to the same underlying array, that should be much safer, because you don't have to take care of allocating/freeing memory. (Besides: your question was only about printing (i.e. *reading*) ptr, not about creating an array it can point to).

Answer (score 0):

`z[0].ptr` will return the `ptr` from the first struct in the vector. To access an element of the array this points to, use `z[0].ptr[n]`.

Answer (score 0):

The same way as you access `z[0].y`:

```
z[0].ptr;
```

However you have to know the array size, if you want to iterate and print its elements. Probably you want to keep an additional `unsigned int size;` inside your `struct`.

You access the elements of the array as usual:

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<z[0].size;i++)
   std::cout << z[0].ptr[i] << std::endl;
```

If your array can change in size, and you don't want to store an additional variable, just use `std::vector` like you did to store your structs.

Remember to first create the array using `new[]` and then delete its contents using `delete[]` when you don't need it. Trying to access memory that doesn't belong to you, will lead to [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: The thing is the unsigned int *ptr is never allocated, it just points to an allocated unsigned int array.

Comment: @user3526793 What do you mean ptr is never allocated?

Comment: @user3526793 I think you don't understand the concept of memory allocation. If the pointer points to allocated memory (no matter when and how it was allocated), the pointer itself is valid, and you can access it like a normal array. Unless it points to some data that was at some point invalidated by using `delete[]` or going out of scope, if it wasn't allocated manually.